# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://dba.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 5):

Well everbody, thanks for participating. As you can see by following this link:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/1

We successfully elected three candidates, namely:

- MrDenny
- JackDouglas
- JColeBrand

as the new moderators of the site.

There was a townhall chat:

[2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  Tuesday October 4th, 22:00 UTC / 6pm Eastern](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-tuesday-october-4th-2200-utc-6pm-e)

that took place and here's the transcript:

[2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)

And that wraps that up. For any further questions, feel free to ask a new question on meta and tag it [election](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election)

Comment: jcolebrand, mrdenny & JackDouglas - Congrats!!! Keep up the good work... :)