# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  Tuesday October 4th, 22:00 UTC / 6pm Eastern

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the [moderator elections](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/1), we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 4th at 10pm UTC / 6pm EDT.**

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=10&day=4&year=2011&hour=22&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1497/dba-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. I'm operating on the assumption that there won't be a primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 4th-6th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=dba.stackexchange.com).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Huzzah. See y'all tomorrow.

Comment: Lordy that's late: midnight here.

Comment: @gbn I think we are going to just have to grin and bear it - it is probably 3am for someone :)