# I somehow miss a post about the results about the 2011 moderator election

Tags: support

From [2011 Community Moderator Election](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/2011-community-moderator-election) I see that 3 candidates where found and 
[2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)
seems to be a further step in the procedure.

But I miss the clear statement, that those 3 candidates did indeed became the elected moderators.

Comment: I'm afraid they did indeed - ["we successfully elected three candidates"](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/2011-community-moderator-election/459#459)

Comment: Then congratulation to you, MrDenny and JColeBrand.

Comment: Thanks! I hope we can all keep on working together making this site a great resource - quality content is what will make the difference so please keep churning it out (while we get rid of the spam etc) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always view election results, forever, at

https://dba.stackexchange.com/election

Your current moderators are visible, with election details summarized, at

https://dba.stackexchange.com/about

if you scroll to the bottom.